# How does JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter work in this example?

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Below is my example of Configuration, as far as I understand, JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter works first ( it gets username, password from request, checks if they are correct and provides a token ), then - JwtTokenVerifier.

I have a few questions:

1. Is JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter checks requests every time for containing username and password? If not, when does it check it? Once per what?
2. Why do we create Authentication object in JwtTokenVerifier class with no password ( just username and Authorities )  and put it in Context?

P.S. I do appreciate your answers! And know how dumb the question may seems to be.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, secretKey))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig),JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }


public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;
    private final SecretKey secretKey;

    public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                      JwtConfig jwtConfig,
                                                      SecretKey secretKey) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            );

            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            return authenticate;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(jwtConfig.getTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
                .signWith(secretKey)
                .compact();

        response.addHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader(), jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + token);
    }
}

public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final SecretKey secretKey;
private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

public JwtTokenVerifier(SecretKey secretKey,
                        JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
    this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader());

    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix())) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.replace(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix(), "");

    try {

        Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(token);

        Claims body = claimsJws.getBody();

        String username = body.getSubject();

        var authorities = (List<Map<String, String>>) body.get("authorities");

        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = authorities.stream()
                .map(m -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(m.get("authority")))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username,
                null,
                simpleGrantedAuthorities
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    } catch (JwtException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Token %s cannot be trusted", token));
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter` extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and by default its triggered when you make a "POST" call to "/login". This can be changed by calling the `setFilterProcessesUrl(<PATH_HERE>)` in the `JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter`'s constructor.
2. You don't keep the password in the Authentication object simply because it's not needed, and it's safer to keep the password off-memory because anyone with access to the memory dump can retrieve the password.